# camera intent app crash

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, imageview

Hey can somebody help me please.
i can take picture and it will shown in the gallery, but i cant set in an imageview. the app crashes.
my code

maybe something is wrong in the activityresult??

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {




                intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";

                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(camtest.this, authorities, photoFile);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);



                if (photoFile != null) {
                    imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(camtest.this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
                            photoFile);
                    Log.i("Uri", imageUri.toString());
//                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                }
                else{
                    Log.i("Uri", "none");
                }
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(photoFile)));

                startActivityForResult(intent, 7);




            }
        });
```

File create method:

```
 File createImageFile() throws IOException {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "LetsTalk_img" + timeStamp;
        File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg", storageDirectory);
        mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(image)));
        return image;

    }
```

and the onactivityresult:
is here a mistake by me?

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {



        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How about the most important of it all: the stacktrace?

Comment: You should not invoke the media scanner in onClick(). Much to early. The user can even decide not to take a picture. Move the mediascanner code to onActivityResult().

Comment: You try to obtain a bitmap in onActivityResult. But you will not get one as you use EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

You just put `cameraIntent()` method in your button click function.

```
private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

And then after paste this.

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == 0){
                    onCaptureImageResult(data);
           }
            }
        }
```

for setting in a thumbnail pass the data in your ImageView variable like this:

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imagebox.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
```

Comment: Do i Need sd Card for this?

Comment: I have Not an externalstoragedirectory

Comment: No, it can save in your phone memoery also.

Comment: Ok. I will test it at evening

Comment: `I have Not an externalstoragedirectory `. You have. Every device has. But why would you try this code? It saves a thumnail to file. Do you need a thumbnail on file? And worse: No full original file will be produced and saved to file by the camera app anymore. So no picture in your Gallery app. Stay with your original intent and code and solve the problems.

Comment: Ok i dont want a Thumbnail. I want the fullsize image in a imageview. Can you tell me how can i get it Working?